# jQuery/Javascript - Get value of text input field, and display in div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am testing getting a text input, and printing the result in a div below. However, I can't see to get it to work.

If the "placeholder" of the input field to a "value", it inexplicably works. I may just be tired, and missing something obvious, but I can't for the life of me work out what's wrong.

```js
//Tested and didn't work
//var URL = document.getElementById("download")[0].value;
//var URL = document.getElementsByName("download")[0].value;

var URL = $('#download').val();

function downloadURL() {
    //Print to div
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = URL;
    //Test, just in case innerHTML wasn't working
    alert(URL);
}
```

```html
<p><input type="text" name="download" id="download" placeholder="Download URL"></p>
<button onclick="downloadURL()">Test</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: You have to get the changed value inside the function, right now you're getting the value once, before the function runs, and store it in a variable, then you use that same value over and over again, as the variable doesn't update when it's outside the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a small change, you have to get value when you click on button, so first save a reference to that field and then get value when required

```
var URL = $('#download');

function downloadURL(){
   //Print to div
   document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = URL.val();
   // alert(URL.val());
}
```

Comment: This works for the div, though the alert says [object Object]... though I guess that doesn't matter too much

Comment: change alert(URL) to alert(URL.val()).. I forgot to change that

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go jQuery...

```
var URL = $('#download');

function downloadURL() {
    $("#output").html(URL.val());
}
```

... or plain JavaScript

```
var URL = document.getElementById("download") ;

function downloadURL() {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = URL.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to stick with `jQuery`. Let `jQuery` behave in an unobtrusive way instead of relying on an inline event handler attached to the `button`.

```
<p> <input type="text" name="download" id="download" placeholder="Download URL"></p>
<button>Test</button> //remove the inline click handler                      
<div id="output"></div>

$('button').on('click', function() {
  var url = $('#download').val();
  $('#output').text(url); //or append(), or html(). See the documentation for further information 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Minor modifications on your code so that it can be aligned to "[Unobtrusive Javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)".

**HTML**

```
<p> 
    <input type="text" name="download" id="download" placeholder="Download URL">
</p>
<button id="btnDownloadUrl">Test</button>                          
<div id="output"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
    $("#btnDownloadUrl").bind("click", function(){
        var downloadUrl = $("#download").val();
        $("#output").html(downloadUrl);
    });
});
```

Comment: Be sure to name that callback function or,  preferably, define it outside and pass its name as a callback argument.